# Regex doesn't match all foreign characters

Tags: c#, regex, xunit

Here's my regex `^([\\p{L}-|a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)$` and it is supposed to allow all foreign letters as well as numeric letter, number. But for some reason, hindi characters cannot match.

I wrote a Xunit test to prove.

```
[Fact]
        public void test()
        {
            var hindiChar = "इम्तहान";
            var input = "12345ABCDPrüfungテスト中文테스트إسرائيل" + hindiChar;
            var regex = "^([\\p{L}-|a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)$";
            Assert.True(new Regex(regex).IsMatch(input));
        }
```

If you remove the `hindiChar`, the test will return true; but if you add the `hindiChar`, the test will return false.

I thought part of the regex is to fit all foreign characters, but not sure why it doesn't match hindi characters.

Comment: It is a known fact that `\p{L}` only matches letters from the BMP plane. Do you want to match diacritics too? Add `\p{M}`. Use `@"^[\p{M}\p{L}-|a-zA-Z0-9-_]+$"`. What is the `|` there for? Note the `|` inside a character class matches a literal `|` char. It seems to me you wan to use `@"^[\p{L}\p{M}0-9_-]+$"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks it worked. The `|` is `or` as in this regex allows foreign characters `or` numeric, numbers.

Comment: Ok, `[|]` is not an *or* operator, and here `|` must be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not enough to use `\p{L}` to match words, you also need to match diacritics. That can be done by adding `\p{M}` to your regex. Note that even the `\w` shorthand "word" character class in .NET regex by default also matches a set of diacritics, `\p{Mn}` (*Mark, Nonspacing* Unicode char category), see [this .NET regex reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#WordCharacter). However, here you need `\p{M}` to allow any diacritics.

Note that `|` inside a character class matches a literal `|` char, so you need to remove the `|` from your pattern.

It seems to me you use

```
@"^[\p{L}\p{M}0-9_-]+$"
```

It will match any string of one or more letters, diacritics, ASCII digits, `_` or `-` chars.

See the [**regex demo**](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%5B%5Cp%7BL%7D%5Cp%7BM%7D0-9_-%5D%2B%24&i=12345ABCDPr%C3%BCfung%E3%83%86%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E4%B8%AD%E6%96%87%ED%85%8C%EC%8A%A4%ED%8A%B8%D8%A5%D8%B3%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%A6%D9%8A%D9%84%E0%A4%87%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%B9%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A8).

Note that in case you want to allow any Unicode digit chars, you may even use

```
@"^[\w\p{M}-]+$"
```

See [another demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%5B%5Cw%5Cp%7BM%7D-%5D%2B%24&i=12345ABCDPr%C3%BCfung%E3%83%86%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E4%B8%AD%E6%96%87%ED%85%8C%EC%8A%A4%ED%8A%B8%D8%A5%D8%B3%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%A6%D9%8A%D9%84%E0%A4%87%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%B9%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A8)